# Listview row divide and click

Tags: android, xml, listview, onclick, textview

Frankly, I try to make a xml like contacts list when you click someone and appear on his/her number and there is call his/her or send sms to his/her views. And these have different click item clicks. I try to make it with textview and lsitview. But when I use the textviews, the listview's first one is divided 2 field. But they havent different clicks when I click to each of one , the all line is clicked. But I want to manage them separately.

```
 TextView   TextView
 -------------------
 ListViewItem
 -------------------
 ListViewItem
   .
   .
   .
```

I used this site http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/ for divide the lsitview to 2 textview

Comment: You want separately click event of each view within listview, Right?

Comment: Yes, I want to click event of each textview the first listview item's. I just want to click on the first one, the others can clickable only as a listview item, the first listview item contains 2 textview for each can click

Answer (score -1):

**Use The below Code do so**

```
 package com.app.listdnd;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ListDnD extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private ListView lvList;
        private EfficientAdapter mAdapter;
        private ArrayList<String> ;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            lvList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lsone);
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("One");
            list.add("Two");
            list.add("Three");
            list.add("Four");
            list.add("Five");
            list.add("Six");

            mAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
            lvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int pos) {
                return pos;
            }

            public long getItemId(int pos) {
                return pos;
            }

            public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.newsstand_listrow,
                            null);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.item = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
holder.item1 = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView2);


                    holder.item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.e("GetClick...", "TextView");
                        }
                    });
holder.item1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.e("GetClick...", "TextView1");
                        }
                    });
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.item.setText(list.get(pos));
                return convertView;
            }

            class ViewHolder {
                TextView item,item1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you should ellaborate your answer.

Comment: This doesn't even solve the problem. Did you even read the question? Infact this is copied from API Demos i believe.